# TCP/HTTP Rendezvous (Relay) Proxy

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, network-protocols

I am looking for a specific kind of proxy that is meant to operate in a rendezvous mode, such that two nodes can make an outgoing connection to the same proxy, send a routing token, and have their packets relayed to each other from that point.

Proxy servers like HAProxy would be perfect but AFAIK they do not offer something like that: the goal of the proxy in this case is to make another outgoing connection and route the packets to that location. In this case, I want two nodes to connect to the proxy, and have their packets relayed between them through the proxy, after sending a routing token that can be used to associate the two nodes.

I could write my own server to perform such type of relaying, but I am wondering if something already exists to do something like this. I am looking for such a solution as a fallback for cases where NAT traversal protocols like ICE/STUN/TURN are not feasible due to a highly restricted network environment that does not allow UDP traffic. The base protocol for the proxy could be TCP, HTTP or WebSocket, which would be easier to allow in a firewall with a simple rule.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I believes SOCKSv5 has everything you are asking for.

> two nodes can make an outgoing connection to the same proxy. send a routing token, and have their packets relayed to each other from that point.

The routing token in this case would be the endpoint address and/or the user credentials. I would first look at the supper simple implementation built into the 'ssh' utility, this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel) goes over how to get everything set up. If you need something more granular then look into [dante](https://www.inet.no/dante/).

The only tricky part is when you try to use the user credential option with SOCKv5 as it is not as well supported in browsers, but is possible with addons.